# System font are not available in Libreoffice

Tags: linux, gnome, fonts, gui, libreoffice

Gnome is set to use `Monospace Regular` for Monospace Text. However when I open `Libreoffice Writer` that is bundled with my distribution, I cannot select that font in the GUI. How can I make the font usable for all programs, not just the system?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/32088/some-fonts-dont-appear-in-libreoffice. If not, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/735581/edit) your question to add what you tried and with what results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the UI font for LibreOffice in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608198/changing-the-ui-font-for-libreoffice-in-linux)